# How I can insert the value of a table to another table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I know how to insert data into table. But my problem now is I don't know how to insert the table 1 value to another table. I haven't tried anything yet.
 [Click this to see the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCsEn.png)

Comment: What you have try?

Comment: Nothing yet....

Comment: then please go for: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I have two tables

`TABLE A` which is empty.

`TABLE B` which contains Data.

I want to display `table B` data to `table A`

```
<table id="TableA">
  <!-- <tbody></tbody> -->
</table>
<br/>

<table id="TableB" style="border:solid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td id="col1">Column 1</td>
      <td id="col2">Column 2</td>
      <td id="col3">Column 3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data a</td>
      <td>Data b</td>
      <td>Data c</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Just add this script tag in your Javascript file. It will copy all the data from `TABLE B` and paste it in `TABLE A`.

```
function copytable() {
  var source = document.getElementById('TableB');
  var destination = document.getElementById('TableA');
  var copy = source.cloneNode(true);
  copy.setAttribute('id', 'tableA');
  destination.parentNode.replaceChild(copy, destination);
}
setTimeout(function() {
  copytable();
}, 0);
```